# "AuthEffects.googleSignIn" dispatched an invalid action and Actions must have a type property

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, rxjs, ngrx

I keep getting the following errors:

- Effect "AuthEffects.googleSignIn" dispatched an invalid action: [object Object]
- Uncaught TypeError: Actions must have a type property

as seen below:

[image]
[image]

How do I resolve it? The sign in happens as expected but I am not sure how to go about fixing it:

**auth.effects.ts**

```
  @Effect()
  googleSignIn = this.actions.pipe(
    ofType(authActions.googleSignIn),
    mergeMap(() =>
      from(this.authService.googleSignIn()).pipe(
        map(() => this.getAuthData,
          catchError(err =>
            of({ error: err.message })
          )
        )
      )
    )
  );

  @Effect()
  getAuthData = this.actions.pipe(
    ofType(authActions.getAuthData),
    mergeMap(() => (
        this.afAuth.authState.pipe(
          map((authData: AuthState) => {
            if (authData) {
              const parsedAuthData: Partial<AuthState> = this.authService.parseAuthData(authData);
              return authActions.authDataRetrieved({ payload: parsedAuthData });
            } else {
              return authActions.authDataNotRetrieved();
            }
          }),
          catchError(error => {
            this.logger.debug(error);
            return of(authActions.authError({ errorMessage: error.message, errorCode: error.code }));
          })
        )
      )
    )
  );
```

**auth.actions.ts**

```
import { createAction, props } from '@ngrx/store';
import { AuthState } from './auth.state';

export const getAuthData = createAction('[Auth] Get authentication data');
export const authDataRetrieved = createAction('[Auth] Authentication data retrieved', props<{payload: Partial<AuthState>}>());
export const authDataNotRetrieved = createAction('[Auth] Authentication data not retrieved');
export const googleSignIn = createAction('[Auth] Google sign-in attempt start');
export const authError = createAction('[Auth] Authentication error occurred', props<{ errorMessage: string, errorCode: string }>());
```

Comment: Your googleSignIn effect doesn't dispatch an action. In your current syntax, try adding a config object `{ dispatch: false }` to the `@Effect` decorator.

Comment: you are using effect v7 try to use v8 and also can you make full working code demo on stackblitz please

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should return an action from your googleSignIn effect some thing like this

```
 getPosts$ = createEffect(() =>
    this.actions$.pipe(
      ofType(PostActions.LoadPosts),
      switchMap(_ => {
        return this.postService
          .getPosts()
          .pipe(
            map(
              (posts: IPost[]) => PostActions.LoadPostsSuccess({ posts }), // return an action here
              catchError(errors => of(PostActions.LoadPostsFail(errors)))
            )
          );
      })
    )
  );
```

I'm point out where is your error so you can fix it

```
@Effect()
  googleSignIn = this.actions.pipe(
    ofType(authActions.googleSignIn),
    mergeMap(() =>
      from(this.authService.googleSignIn()).pipe(
        map(() => this.getAuthData, // you need to return an action here
          catchError(err =>
            of({ error: err.message })
          )
        )
      )
    )
  );
```